# Setting the last-modified-time of a directory opened for ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: java, windows, winapi, createfile, readdirectorychangesw

I hava a Java program that needs to monitor a directory tree for changes.  I have JNI code that uses `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`.  The directory is opened like:

```
HANDLE dirHandle = CreateFile(
    path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL
);
```

and then I pass `dirHandle` to `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`.  All of that works just fine.

The problem is that other parts of the code (on the Java side) use `File.setLastModified()` to "touch" files or directories (update their timestamps to be "now").  This generally works; however, it fails when it tried to "touch" the directory that was opened using `CreateFile()`.

To see what Windows error is actually occurring, I looked at the JDK source for `File.setLastModified()` and reimplemented it in my own code with the addition of printing the error from `GetLastError()`; the error is:

```
ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION (error 32)
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
```

WTF?  It's the *same* process. I even passed `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to `CreateFile()`.

Is there a way to make this work?

### More Info

The native code implementation of `File.setLastModified()` in the JDK does a:

```
h = CreateFileW(pathbuf, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
```

If I change the first `0` to `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, it all works.  So it seems that the JDK implementation is a little broken. :(

So my question now becomes: Is there a way to make this work without having to use my own (re)implementation of `File.setLastModified()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error message is a bit misleading in this case, what you're seeing is normal behaviour.

By opening the directory with `dwShareMode` set to zero, the JDK is, in effect, asking for exclusive access, which will cause any other access attempt to fail with a sharing violation error. This applies equally to accesses
from other processes and from within your own process.

The [`CreateFile` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) describes the `dwShareMode` parameter:

> If this parameter is zero and CreateFile succeeds, the file or device cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the file or device is closed.
>
> You cannot request a sharing mode that conflicts with the access mode that is specified in an existing request that has an open handle. `CreateFile` would fail and the `GetLastError` function would return `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

So, it seems you've answered your own question: you need a custom `setLastModified` function that specifies `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` when accessing the directory.

Comment: Yes, buy WHY is the JDK asking for exclusive access?  It doesn't seem necessary in this case.